# How write correctly a Docker file to build war file and run spring-boot maven project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11

RUN mvn clean install

RUN mvn spring-boot:run
```

Then run,

```
$ docker image build -t  hello-world .
```

**when i run above command then following error would occurred.**

Sending build context to Docker daemon  206.6MB

Step 1/3 : FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
---> 918519009705

Step 2/3 : RUN mvn clean install
---> Running in d915d2ac25e7

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time:  0.153 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-11T12:33:30Z

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException

**Now, Can you explain a proper way to build(.war file) and run a maven project using docker image for windows?**

Comment: You haven't `COPY`ed any content into your image, so Maven can't find the `pom.xml` file or any of your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **copy the pom.xml** as well as the **source code** so that they are available within the container for building. Then you may do the run step.

Example:

```
### BUILD image
FROM maven:3-jdk-11 as builder
# create app folder for sources
RUN mkdir -p /build
WORKDIR /build
COPY pom.xml /build
#Download all required dependencies into one layer
RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins
#Copy source code
COPY src /build/src
# Build application
RUN mvn package
```

Code snippet from https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-run-and-build-in-docker
Visit for full explanation.

Comment: After building docker image successfully, Run **docker run <image_name>:tag**
following error would show:
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.

Comment: But the error you posted above shows that it's happening on step 2/3 which the mvn clean install step. I don't understand what you image is build successfully.